# Rails 5.1 Running System Tests on Puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I was wondering if there was a way to use the Puma server (Rails default) JUST on the new Rails 5.1 system tests?

Right now on all our projects we use tiny_tds, but I was trying to experiment with 5.1 system tests with Capybara/Selenium but it fails of course because I do not have Puma installed/running.

I took a look through the documentation and didn't see anything about declaring what type of server you want to use. Were connecting to a SQL Server database so I don't know if Puma is able to do that (And that's probably why were using tiny_tds in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing database adapters and rack web servers which are very different things.

Puma (like Webrick, Thin, Unicorn etc) is a general purpose [Rack](https://rack.github.io/) web server.  It sits and waits for incoming requests from vistors and dispatches them to an application (like a Rails app) by calling it with a hash containing the environment and request. The application returns an array containing the response. The server sends it back to the visitor.

`tiny_tds` on the other hand is a database adapter. Its used to connect the application to the database. The web server is almost completly oblivious to how the application creates a response from the request. This includes whatever databases are used.

In Rails 5 most servers  don't require configuration. You just add the gem to the gemfile and run `bundle install` and they plug themselves in. There in no seperate installation step.

That was not the case earlier which is why Webrick - a server with the only real merit being that it does not require configuration was the default. It is now Puma which unlike Webrick is suited for production.

Using different servers in different environments is not a good idea since it violates the idea of [dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity). Your dev & test environment should be as close as possible to what you are deploying to so that you can catch bugs before they end up in production. This means you should be running the same server, same database etc.

Running a seperate test server for different parts of your test suite sounds like a true fools errand - if its even possible without hacking the framework to bits.

For SQL Server there is [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) which can use `tiny_tds` as a backend.

Comment: Regardless I still need to put puma in the gemfile right? even if it's the default now? Since it seems not included in this projects gemfile (which is def. a 5.1 rails project)

Comment: Puma is included in the gemfile when you generate a app with Rails 5.1. Running `rails new` by default also runs bundle install so it should be installed. I just tested it.

Comment: But yes if you want to use puma add the gem to the gemfile and run bundle install.